# Zoom support while page curling effect present in pdf reader app

Tags: iphone, ipad, pdf, cgpdfdocument, uiviewanimationtransition

Hi
I am developing an ipad Magazine app where I need to display pdf files.I am using [leaves](https://github.com/objectivecdeveloper/leaves) project for page curl effect.This works great.
But in landscape page fits to height(768px) and it becomes difficult to read the font.
Thats why I want to support zoom in/out on this view.
I am a newbie to Core Graphics.I think in leaves project they parse pdf to show image of each page.But I dont know why zoom is not supported if it is an image.
There are some more branches of leaves project for implementing this feature but all of them are not perfect.
Shall I continue using leaves or UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp/Down will help me for both the problems?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer [this tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html). Provided by APPLE

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Jennis.Its looking good.will try it out and let you know the results.

Comment: Page curl effect is missing in this project.I know, apple uses private APIS for page curl effect,but I want to enable zoom along with page curl implemented using Leaves project.

Comment: @amavi:did u get the answer??even im looking for the same thing?

Answer (score 6):

here is the code for your requirement. [check out this](https://github.com/hammerlyrodrigo/leaves)

Comment: awesome sujay .it is more help