# PDF reader with page curling effect and zoom function

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, zooming, page-curl

I want to make a PDF reader with page curling effect AND zooming.
I searched a lot and found this [Zoom support while page curling effect present in pdf reader app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225332/zoom-support-while-page-curling-effect-present-in-pdf-reader-app?s=d26915b3-7a2a-4992-a0bb-c55990f18f9f) solution for an pdf reader with a page curling effect and zoom function. 
But how do I combine "Leaves Source Code" and "Zooming PDF Viewer Source Code"? 
Do you have a solution or a Source Code for this?